# Animation by using matplotlib + errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an animation based on this example. My main problem is that i don't know how to connect the animation with errorbar. Maybe somebody has already solved 
something similar ..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    ax.errorbar(x, np.array(x), yerr=1, color='green')
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

#Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    ax.errorbar(x, np.array(x), yerr=1, color='green')
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: and [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html)

Comment: @tcaswell i need something like result of this code but for example it  has to move to right (it - i mean x axes) using  
`animation.FuncAnimation()`

Comment: ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: @tcaswell i've just edited a previous version of my code

Comment: sorry for being snippy, I was in a really bad mood today....

Comment: Keep communication about this issue in-band please

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = gcf()
ax = gca()
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 256)
line, ( bottoms, tops), verts =  ax.errorbar(x, np.sin(x), yerr=1)

verts[0].remove() # remove the vertical lines

yerr = 1
def animate(i=0):
    #    ax.errorbar(x, np.array(x), yerr=1, color='green')
    y = np.sin(x+i/10.0)
    line.set_ydata(y)  # update the data
    bottoms.set_ydata(y - yerr)
    tops.set_ydata(y + yerr)
    return line, bottoms, tops


def init():
    # make an empty frame
    line.set_ydata(np.nan * np.ones(len(line.get_xdata())))
    bottoms.set_ydata(np.nan * np.ones(len(line.get_xdata())))
    tops.set_ydata(np.nan * np.ones(len(line.get_xdata())))
    return line, bottoms, tops


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
    interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

This will get you most of the way there.  Look into the code of how `axes.errorbar` works to understand what it returns.

You misunderstood what `init` does.

If you need to have the vertical lines, look at how the are generate in `axes.errorbar` and just remove and re-create them every frame.  The `collection` based objects do not play nice with updating.

Comment: I encountered the problem that the provided plot command did not produce caplines of the error bars. Also the line,bottom,tops,verts are now bundled in the lines attributes of the ErrorbarContainer. thus I had to change line to `ax.errorbar(x, np.sin(x), yerr=1, capsize=20).lines`